# Running SQ on Azure Devops is not scanning all the files/subfolders/projects especially c# files

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, azure-devops-extensions

So I've followed this guide - [SQ Integration in DevOps](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/azuredevops-integration/)

But even after following the entire process, the SQ is not scanning C# files, when I do it manually using cmd on my windows 10 machine it is able to scan everything, am I missing anything here ??, I'm not getting any errors as such

[image]

[image]

I'm able to get warnings in console, so I'm assuming that the analysis worked, But once the SonarQube kicks in, there's no mention about the files that are there

Btw I have a Xamarin solution and I've created a VS Build pipeline to just build all the projects in the solution

Answer (score 0):

Check this [doc](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/cfamily/):

Analysis of C/C++/Objective-C projects requires the `Build Wrapper`. It runs the build and gathers all the configuration required for correct analysis of C/C++/Objective-C projects (such as macro definitions, include directories, …). The Build Wrapper does not impact your build; it merely eavesdrops on it and writes what it learns into files in a directory you specify.

Since you are using windows 10, we could add a `PowerShell script` task by inserting the below script to make the Build Wrapper available on the build agent

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri '<sonarqube_url>/static/cpp/build-wrapper-win-x86.zip' -OutFile 'build-wrapper.zip'
Expand-Archive -Path 'build-wrapper.zip' -DestinationPath '.'
```

Comment: But there's no C/C++ or objective C files, this is a .NET based Xamarin solution